# How many quadrilaterals can be made with these line segments if circles can be inscribed in the quadrilaterals made$?$

Tags: combinatorics

There are $8$ line segments of lengths(in cm) $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.How many quadrilaterals can be made with these line segments if circles can be inscribed in the quadrilaterals made$?$

---

I made a try at this problem.Since quadrilateral has 4 sides,therefore $\binom{8}{4}$ quadrilaterals are possible,but i cannot identify out of them in which circles can be inscribed.Is there some condition/restriction on the quadrilateral for being circle inscribable.

Comment: You've actually overcounted. Note that if I take side lengths of 1, 2, 3, and 8 there is no way for me to make a quadrilateral, since 1+2+3<8.

Comment: This might be helpful  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral  Specifically the Characterizations part.

Comment: The question asks "how many quadrilaterals". Since a quadrilateral with given sides is not rigid, specifying the sides only does not specify the quadrilateral. For example if all the sides are the same length, any rhombus with that side length (an uncountable number of incongruent quadrilaterals) will have an incircle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much stronger necessary (and in fact sufficient) condition than the triangle inequality:

It is a well-known fact that a quadrilateral with sides $a,b,c,d$ has an incircle iff $a+c=b+d$. Can you think of the reason for this?

So you have to count the number of quadruples $\{a,b,c,d\} \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ satisfying $a+c=b+d$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: I think this is what the question intends, but see my comment on the question about the lengths of the sides not specifying the quadrilateral since a quadrilateral is not a rigid figure in the plane.

Comment: Sir answer given is 22.Do i have to manually count,I understood logic given by you.But is it possible to answer without manual counting@Tintarn

Comment: @user1442: I don't think there is a "magic" way to do this. But of course one can count in a clever way distinguishing the possible sums of opposite sides..